# android imageslider

Tags: android, image, slider, gallery, viewflipper

I am looking for a way to build an imageslider that works similar to ViewFlipper - user navigates through images by sliding with finger left or right. The problem with ViewFlipper is that when I download lot of images from web than the app runs out of memory. I also use AsyncTask to load images into ViewFlipper but I have feeling that I'll need to do a lot of complex work in order to make this work as I imagined.
Is there already solution for such problem that I can modify and implement in my app?

Here's what I currently have:

```
package com.example.viewflippertest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewFlipper vf; 
    private float lastX;

    public String[] photos = {
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/538.jpg",
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/528.jpg",
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/541.jpg",
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/542.jpg",
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/543.jpg",
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/544.jpg",
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/514.jpg",
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/511.jpg",          
            "http://ilijaveselica.com/Uploads/Photos/545.jpg"
    }; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

        vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);  

        new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();   

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {

        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                lastX = touchevent.getX();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                float currentX = touchevent.getX();

                if (lastX < currentX)
                {
                    if (vf.getDisplayedChild()==0)
                        break;

                    vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
                    vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
                    vf.showPrevious();
                }

                if (lastX > currentX)
                {
                    if (vf.getDisplayedChild()==vf.getChildCount()-1)
                        break;

                    vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
                    vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
                    vf.showNext();
                }

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                float tempX = touchevent.getX();
                int scrollX = (int) (tempX - lastX);

                //vf.scrollBy(scrollX, 0);

                break;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }




    public static Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,
    IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }  

    public static Drawable ImageOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }


    private class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

        Map<String,Drawable> imagesMap = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();  
        int photosCounter = 0;

            @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //myProgress = 0;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
           }

            @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);             

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

                for(int i=0;i<photos.length;i++)
                {                   
                    Drawable image =ImageOperations(photos[i]);                 

                    imagesMap.put(String.valueOf(i), image);

                    photosCounter++;

                    if(i == 2)
                        break;  
                }


                spinner.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for(int i=0;i<photosCounter;i++)
                {                   
                    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(imagesMap.get(String.valueOf(i)));

                    vf.addView(imageView);  
                }   

            }


       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should load your bitmap Efficiently here below link provide complete guidance, how to efficiently download image from web

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache and possibly resize your images, see:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

for a full worked example.